# percent encoding - how is a greek letter percent encoded?

Tags: character-encoding, url-encoding

I'm browsing the web for a answer but cannot find one. I have a HTML form (method=GET) and submit in a text field the text helloΩ  (hello with the greek letter Omega appended)

The URL in the browser encodes it as:

```
mytext=hello%26%23937%3B
```

Without the greek letter Omega appended, I get (as expected):

```
mytext=hello
```

So how is the greek Omega letter percent encoded into:

```
%26%23937%3B
```

Thanks

Comment: it looks like it's HTML-encoded (`&#937;`) and then percent-encoded. I would expect percent-encoded UTF-8 instead: `%CE%A9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your web server declared an encoding that doesn't support the character. For example, `ISO-8859-1` doesn't support it which is the default encoding for many web servers.

That's a html entity character reference percent-encoded: `&#937;`, because `#`, `&` .. are all ASCII characters, this is the only way to not lose information because the browser thinks the server only supports ISO-8859-1.

To fix this, declare `UTF-8` in your http header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This isn't even consistent behavior between browsers, because IE encodes it as `hello%D9`, which is `Ú` in CP1252/ISO-8859-1.

Comment: thanks... I was wondering what could have caused the HTML-encoding.

Comment: It’s a bit more complicated. The behavior (which is nonstandard, just browser practice) depends on the encoding of the form data in submission. This in turn is the same as the encoding of the page, unless there is an `charset` attribute in the `form` tag. The encoding of the page depends on HTTP headers in part, but unless specified there, it might be determined by other factors, such as a `meta` tag.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela On top of that, the user can also override page encoding manually. But in the general case simply setting the http header will work because generally `accept-charset` is not used, and the http header overrides the meta tag.

Comment: Excellent! So we are saying that if the browser does not think the server supports the submitted character it then replaces it with a character reference and then the normal percent encoding happens.

Comment: @user1207420 yes, if the browser happens to be firefox or chrome. But really, use utf-8, so you can support any character someone can submit correctly :) You will see it's working, when omega is encoded as `%CE%A9`

Comment: as you suggest, ie9 behaves differently. It encodes it as %CE%A9 regardless the encoding of the page. I encoded a static page as ascii and also specified `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ascii"/>` and then submitted to the server the omega character. All 3 browsers submitted in Cp1252 character encoding (my platform default), chrome/firefox submitted it as **%26%23937%3B** whereas ie9 submitted as **%CE%A9**, I believe Cp1252 does not support greek characters

Comment: my last comment now seems incorrect. I've re-tested and ie9 behaves the same as firefox/chrome but it wasn't before. It must have cached something inbetween my page refreshes (when I changes the encoding of the static page on the server)